# Stacked bar chart from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame which is 4 columns and 588 rows (an excerpt of this is at the end)

From this data frame, can I produce a stacked bar chart where the X axis is the month, and that bar is split into the appropriately sized bars for each day?

| T | year | month | day | cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013 | 1 | 1 | 352 |
| 2 | 2013 | 1 | 2 | 502 |
| 3 | 2013 | 1 | 3 | 498 |
| 4 | 2013 | 1 | 4 | 599 |
| 5 | 2013 | 1 | 5 | 521 |
| 6 | 2013 | 1 | 6 | 393 |
| 7 | 2013 | 1 | 7 | 341 |
| 8 | 2013 | 2 | 1 | 370 |
| 9 | 2013 | 2 | 2 | 462 |
| 10 | 2013 | 2 | 3 | 455 |
| 11 | 2013 | 2 | 4 | 450 |
| 12 | 2013 | 2 | 5 | 517 |
| 13 | 2013 | 2 | 6 | 399 |
| 14 | 2013 | 2 | 7 | 355 |
| 15 | 2013 | 3 | 1 | 447 |
| 16 | 2013 | 3 | 2 | 445 |
| 17 | 2013 | 3 | 3 | 458 |
| 18 | 2013 | 3 | 4 | 462 |
| 19 | 2013 | 3 | 5 | 630 |
| 20 | 2013 | 3 | 6 | 556 |
| 21 | 2013 | 3 | 7 | 469 |

Comment: Probably lots of ways, but yep: `barplot(xtabs(cols ~ day + month, data = dat))` for instance. Check out the previous discussions and see if one of those answers works for you - https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5br%5d%20stacked%20barplot

Comment: So up to 31 segments on your bars? It's possible - easy even, but the end result will be next to indecipherable. I would choose a different visualisation - perhaps a calendar heat map - see https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/calendar-chart.html

Comment: @AllanCameron - that visualisation looks impressive - never knew of that type before

Comment: @AllanCameron - have you any examples of this? I have seen a few and the data looks horribly complex - perhaps my data is too simplistic?

Comment: @Joseph. The data needn't be complex at all. You can make a calendar heatmap from just two variables - the date and some numeric value for the fill color. The difficult part is arranging the cells representing dates into a nice grid, though a simplistic one would have year-month on the y axis and day of month on the x axis.

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you could post a data sample, including a data frame, so anyone can copy/paste and run the code. In the absence of that, try this concept.

```
library(plotly)
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
fig
```

[image]

Source:

https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart